# javascript get substring based on character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an RSS feed that supplies a value of

author@email.com (Author)

I know I can use

```
author = author.split('(')[1];
```

But this still leaves

Author)

I realize I can just do another split

```
author = author.split(')')[0];
```

But is there a way to do this in one line?

Here is my code

```
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var author = $(this).find('author').text();
            author = author.split('(')[1];
            author = author.split(')')[0];
            var description = $(this).find('description').text();
            var guid = $(this).find('guid').text();
```

Comment: `\((.+?)\)` This regex can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with regex.

```js
var author = "author@email.com (Author)";
var result = author.replace(/.*\(|\)/g,"")
console.log(result);
```

This does simply replace everything before `(` and the last `)`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: @onThe Please don't forget to click the checkmark then :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to get rid of the last character in the string, you could use the `slice` method. The first parameter is the start position (counting from zero) and the second parameter is the end position. You can use a negative index to count from the back (e.g. -1 is the last character, -2 is the second to last).

Using this, you could write:

```
author = author.split('(')[1].slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: While not a bad idea, author names will vary. So it wont work

Comment: @onTheInternet This should work for any author name.

Comment: As long as the bracket is the last character, this will always work, because it uses the -1 syntax as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression with capturing groups:

```
var authorRegex = /^(.*)\s+\((.*)\)$/;
var authorInfo = authorRegex.exec(author);
var email = authorInfo[1];
var name = authorInfo[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain together the functions you already have to do this in a single line.

```
var author = $(this).find('author').text().split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead to use split, in this case you could try a regular expression with replace, like:

```
author = author.replace(/^.+\(([^\(\)]+)\)[\s\t]*$/, '$1');
```

It saves the text inside the `()` at the end of the string, and it substitute it to the whole string.